# Problem with widgets in Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento-2.1, interceptor

I'm getting the next message when I try to add a widget on a block;

```
Insert Widget... 

There has been an error processing your request

Class Magento\Widget\Controller\Adminhtml\Widget\Index\Interceptor does not exist
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like the `Interceptor` class is not found, which is a generated one. Make sure you run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to rebuild the autogenerated code.

Comment: Good to hear! I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `Interceptor` class is not found, which is a generated one. Make sure you run `bin/magento setup:di:compile` to rebuild the autogenerated code.